# Basic test fails on nightwatch phantomjs browser

Tags: node.js, selenium, phantomjs, nightwatch.js

I am using selenium server, nightwatch on node.js and phantomjs for selenium. I use phantomjs just for headless browser (with it selenium doesn't open browser visually when running tests).

My basic test passes when I use firefox as the browser but fails when I use phantomjs browser.

I setup basic google test:

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=btnG]')
      .pause(1000)
      .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
      .end();
  }
};
```

And setup phantomjs server. This is my nightwatch.json:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "server_path" : "selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 3001,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 3001,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "phantomjs.binary.path" : "phantomjs.exe"       
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I set browserName to "firefox", test passes, "OK. 3 assertions passed.".
But when it is "phantomjs", one passes, one fails, and one error during execution: " TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution, 1 assertions failed, 1 passed. (3.511s)".

With errors:

1. Timed out while waiting for element to be present for 1000 milliseconds. - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
2. ERROR: Unable to locate element: "input[type=text]" using: css selector

I start server manually.

I tested with latest version of phantomjs (2.1.1) and with 1.9.8

EDIT:

Selenium server also reports this error when using phantomjs:

WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP.

Answer (score 2):

I encoutnered something like this in the past and observed that Default size of phantomjs browser was very small. Could you please try resizing browser and check what happens.

Something like below,

`module.exports = {
  'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .resizeWindow(1000, 800);
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=btnG]')
      .pause(1000)
      .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
      .end();
  }
};`

Comment: tnx for the response, but it doesn't work, it's the same as before.
btw. the response I got about this from nightwatch is: "Probably google is doing some javascript magic based on the User-Agent to avoid automated scraping or similar."

Comment: Sorry it didn't help!! Please update this thread if you find something on this.

Comment: @Shri thanks .resizeWindow(1000, 800) worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, resizing the browser window may solve this problem. We are running our test suite in Phantom JS and we have set this in code when we initialize the browser window:

```
client.maximizeWindow();
```